# Getting return value of a Coroutine in unity

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to insert a user to external database in unity. 
I need to wait until web server replies with a error or success, but I'm unable to do it....

Here is what I have done until now:

```
public class DBConnector : MonoBehaviour
{
    string BASE_URL = "https://www.XXXXXX.com/API/";

    public DBConnector()
    {
    }

    public int registerUser(User user)
    {
        int returnInt = -1;

        StartCoroutine(RegisterUser(user, returnValue =>
        {
            returnInt = returnValue;
        }
        ));

        Debug.Log(returnInt);
        return returnInt;
    }

    IEnumerator RegisterUser(User user, System.Action<int> callback = null)
    {
        Debug.Log("a register user");

        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();

        using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(BASE_URL + "userAPI.php", form))
        {
            yield return www.SendWebRequest();

            if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
            {
                Debug.Log(www.error);
                yield return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);

                yield return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and calling it :

```
        Debug.Log("Before registerUser");

        conn = FindObjectOfType<DBConnector>();
        result = conn.registerUser(user);

        Debug.Log("After registerUser");

        if (result == 0)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("AccountCreatedScene");
        }
```

the RegisterUser callback is finished after the registerUser method is finish so always returns -1.

I'm quite newbie on networking thing, so please help.....How to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Note that a Coroutine has nothing to do with *multithreading*!

Answer (score 2):

You need to actually call `callback` with the return value, that's why the delegate you are sending isn't getting called.

```
IEnumerator RegisterUser(User user, System.Action<int> callback = null)
    {
        Debug.Log("a register user");

        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();

        using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(BASE_URL + "userAPI.php", form))
        {
            yield return www.SendWebRequest();

            if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
            {
                Debug.Log(www.error);
                if (callback != null) { callback.Invoke(1); }
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);

                if (callback != null) { callback.Invoke(0); }
            }
        }
    }
```

And you will need to load the scene inside the delegate you send in; that way it will be called after it's done.

```
 public void Register(User user)
    {
        StartCoroutine(RegisterUser(user, returnValue =>
        {
            if (returnValue != 0) { 
              Debug.LogError("Error"); 
              return;
            }

            // Place any logic you want post login
            SceneManager.LoadScene("AccountCreatedScene");
        }
        ));
    }
```

EDIT: Notice this is pseudo code I wrote in the browser.

Answer (score 2):

Also there is a problem:

```
    int returnInt = -1;

    //This is working async so it won't lock your method, just start your Coroutine and go
    StartCoroutine(RegisterUser(user, returnValue =>
    {
        //Inside callback
        returnInt = returnValue;
    }
    ));

    //go over there where your returnInt is always -1; you should insert that log inside callback
    Debug.Log(returnInt);
```

Long story short you should implement rest of the code inside that lambda

returnValue => { /*Here*/ };

or else it will be called before your coroutine finishes

I would do this like this:

```
public void RegisterUser(User user, System.Action<int> callback)
{
    StartCoroutine(RegisterUserCoroutine(user, callback);
}

IEnumerator RegisterUserCoroutine(User user, System.Action<int> callback = null)
{
    Debug.Log("a register user");

    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();

    using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(BASE_URL + "userAPI.php", form))
    {
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
        {
            //This is also bad, because default value of your callback is null, so it would throw an error
            callback(1);

            //This is better
            callback?.Invoke(1);
        }
        else
        {
            callback(0);
        }
    }
}
```

You can't get that int as return value, because you are using async function. So to use that code instead of:

```
int userId = RegisterUser( user );
DoSomethingWithUserId( userId );
```

you should write:

```
RegisterUser( user, DoSomethingWithUserId );
```